# How to know that the output node of an amplifier is not well-defined?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, impedance

There are two questions bothering me that may be related.

1. The first is the gain of a simple MOS transistor. I have read that in today's MOS technology, the intrinsic gain of MOS transistors is between 5 and 10. Yet, the figure below shows that we can get intrinsic gains as high as 500! How come?

[image]

2. The second question is knowing when the output node voltage of an amplifier is not well-defined. The figure below shows a CS stage with a common-source load. Why is the output bias voltage not well defined. How can we know this (intuitively)? Is this somehow connected to impedance of the node?

[image]

Comment: Please add sources of the images you posted, or your question might get deleted.

Comment: Imagine you have two current sources in series and they would fight each other if their values are not matched.

Comment: Leonhard Euler - Hi, As mentioned in a comment above, it is a [rule](/help/referencing) that site members are required to correctly reference any material which is copied from elsewhere & posted on Stack Exchange. Therefore please can you [edit] your question to add a link (for material sourced online) or add title, author, page etc. (for book/magazine & similar which you took a photo of it) for each piece of copied material. Thanks.

Comment: @Leonhard Euler I have updated my answer (because I am pretty sure that the author of the quoted text had the classical CMOS inverter in mind).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple.

No output voltage is well-defined unless there's negative direct or indirect feedback around the amplifier. **You cannot fix a current through an amplifier's drain in an open-loop amplifier.**

If you have defined a current through a drain, then, a DC loop is needed in order to define the right voltage at the gate for the correct Vgs voltage.

**EDIT**

If there existed a transistor that could keep its gain constant not matter what input gate voltage you provide (and on top of that it would see very little deviation from sample to sample), then closed-loop biasing would not be needed.

Unfortunately, such a jewel doesn't exist, to the best of my knowledge.

This was a problem back in the 20s when Harold S. Black saw that those open-loop tube amplifiers were terribly distorting because it had an input-signal dependent gain.

Then, why can a closed-loop amplifier have reliable biasing operating points? **because its input error signal is very small** *(For very well designed ones, of course.)*, due to negative feedback action. This the equivalent assumption you take when analyzing op-amp circuits: V+ = V-. The error signal is V+ - (V-) = 0.

What does this mean? that the swings at the input or output of the amplifiers (except the last stage, which dominates distortion), are very small! Thus, if our gate swings around an voltage operating point (say 300mV for a deep-submicron process). This means that ,if it swings around +/-20mV 300mV, then the usual small-signal analysis, that Razavi's book relies heavily upon, is a good approximation.

If we have an open-loop amplifier (either a current-source or a resistor), then, amplifier's current drain has become a function of the gate voltage, thus, your gm is changing with your signal and the small-signal approximation is bogus.

**EDIT 2: Answer to your 1st question**

The answer to your first question is explicitly shown in the graph you have (The parameter from 50n to 1u looks like the transistor length is parametrized).

Razavi is, most likely, referring to the fact that, modern CMOS process (i.e. very short length transistor) have a very small intrinsic gain. However, that doesn't prevent you from using a longer transistor (length is proportional to intrinsic gain, due to output resistance increase) to increase the gain.

In modern analog designs (current sources, cascodes and amplifying transistors), the minimum length is hardly ever used. I work in a modern process, yet I still use >100nm to get a decent loop gain on my designs.

**EDIT 3 (BONUS): Schematics on how to bias a transistor**

IMHO, it is only useful to bias an amplifier stage within the loop of the amplifier itself.

This is a very practical and simple way to bias and obtain useful design information given a set of specifications.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV4PNF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I simulated, I got that the gate sits at about 4V in order to get a 250mA of current at a drain voltage of 10V (fixed by the large loop gain provided of the amplifier).

Do you know how you'd figure out the output voltage? How would you calculate that?
Well, if the gate voltage is 4V, then the amplifier's output voltage is 8V, why? because the 4V sees the non-inverting transfer towards the output (1+R1/R2).

This simple setup also allows you to estimate whether you have a good chance of meeting your input-referred noise specification.

Say you have already considered how much your resistors will contribute to your input-referred noise budget. How would you know how much current and voltage noise your core amplifier will generate? You can assume, as a rule-of-thumb (this one is!) that your first stage will dominate the input-referred noise. Now you can start sweeping the drain current and the width of your transistor to find your optimum input-referred noise.

You can easily repeat this with an integrated transistor in your IC simulator.

Hope you found my answer helpful

Comment: I think it would be great if you included an explanation, not just a rule-of-thumb.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler it's not a rule-of-thumb! It's fundamental. I'll add some schematics how to do this shortly.

Comment: @ErnestoG In order to fully understand your statements it would be helpful if you would say WHY the current Id cannot be fixed (temperature effects ?, FET tolerances ?,....)

Comment: @LeonhardEuler I have finished my answer. Is there anything else I can help you clarify? Otherwise, I'd really appreciate if you can accept my answer :)

Comment: @ErnestoG, thanks for the response, but your answer didn't answer either question in a satisfactory way. For example, the first figure shows that you can get an intrinsic gain of 50 with almost minimum length transistor (45nm process). Yet, Razavi's book says the intrinsic gain is limited to 5 and 10. For the second question, your answer is too long-winded and includes a lot of unnecessary details.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler alright, let me see if I understand... Razavi said you should be getting a gain of 10 on a "modern process" and, because you get 50, then you think you might be doing something wrong? Could it be he was referring to a 28nm process, perhaps? He didn't specify a node, neither a fab, so I suggest you don't take those statements too literally. About the long answer, well it could probably be better worded or organized, but it is the truth. Good luck with your learning anyway.

Comment: @LvW Temp. effects and tolerances are all valid concerns that feedback helps taming, but the main point remains that the swings must be small (we're amplifying an error signal, not the full input swing) to provide an stable bias. The problem is that the current is a function of gate voltage (you said it yourself in your 1st paragraph), so we cannot amplify linearly unless feedback is used. 
I like your last example, it was also the way stretched linear regions due to feedback were introduced to me as well, but I still think Razavi is talking in general, not about the inverter only.

Comment: @ErnestoG There is one sentence I do not understand: ".the main point remains that the swings must be small (we're amplifying an error signal, not the full input swing) to provide an stable bias."  To me, the bias point is indpendent on the signal swing - unless we are trying to amplify a dc signal.  However, in this case, it is a bit "problematic" to speak about a bias point.

Comment: @LvW "To me, the bias point is indpendent on the signal swing" if the transistor is within a DC feedback loop, then yes.

Comment: @ErnestoG........and when not (DC stabilized)? Why does the bias point depend on the signal in that case?

Comment: @LvW because it's not DC stabilized? Your Q point will move with the signal, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ErnestoG - But my question was "why"? What is the explanation? The signal causes a swing around the bias point but does it change the DC properties?

Comment: I think we're not going to get anywhere in this discussion unless you show me how the bias point is fixed such that input swing is around the bias point. I sense some assumptions in your comment which make this discussion more complex. I'm happy to continue having a friendly discussion with you on the chat if you are up for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem of the quiescent current Id through both transistors is not only temperature-related.
Remember the output characteristics Id1=f(Vds1) for the transistor M1.

For a simple resistive load Rd you can draw the load line - and the crossing with the correct curve (determined by Vgs1) gives the quiescent current Id1 (temperature effects neglected).
This works satisfying because the SLOPE of the load line normally is (a) large if compared with the slope of the curves Id1=f(Vds1) and (b) has a fixed value determined by Rd.

However, in the case under discussion (Fig. 3.18) the resistor Rd is replaced by the transistor M2 and its ouput characteristics  Id2=f(Vds2).
From the drawing it is clear that the circuit forces the equality Id1=Id2.
And this is a problem because this equality requires the correct crossing of two relatively low slopes (with different signs) at the correct point Id1=Id2. Hence, a very accurate matching of Vgs1 and Vgs2 is required.

The situation becomes even more critical when temperature effects are considered (shifting of the curves).

Therefore, an automatic adjustment is needed which can be provided by negative feedback

**UPDATE (EDIT)**
The shown circuit becomes a very versatile (and well-known) linear amplification stage when **(1)** both transistors are complementary to each other (app. the same threshold voltage) and **(2)** the gate nodes are connected to each other as well as to the input signal Vin.

This configuration is the classical **CMOS-Inverter**.

- When condition (1) is fulfilled, both output characteristics Id1=Id2=f(Vds1) meet each other (crossing point) at a voltage which is app. Vds1=Vdd/2.
- Now - when condition (2) is fulfilled and a DC input signal Vin=Vgs1 is applied, the above mentioned working point is met for Vin=Vgs1=Vds1=Vdd/2.
- This gives the classical CMOS inverter transfer curve Vout=Vds1=f(Vin) which crosses the DC working point at Vds1=Vdd/2. This characteristics has a rather steep region around Vdd/2 and can be used for amplification purposes.
- **To fix this bias point a** **feedback resistor Rf** is used which connects the common base node with the common drain node - thus enforcing **Vgs=Vds1**.
- Any ac signal to be amplified is applied through a coupling capacitor (and an additional series resistor in case signal feedback with gain reduction is desired).
- The diagram shows a dc sweep (Vin) from 3V to 9V. Both transistors are not ideally matched - therefore, the steep region of the transfer curve is not centered at 6V. A small resistor R1 between Vin and the common gate node will reduce the slope (and the gain).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It isnt well defined. There are two current sources both of high impedance fighting in series. Let say the above one has higher value then the node has net current being pushed into it so its potential will rise. Since drain potential has risen up the lower transistor increases its current to match and the above transistor has its Vsd reduced so its current decreases.

All this is okay until the increase causes above one to go to linear region ; which may be the case for very high output impedances as higher the value of ro  ; higher the change in Vout to make the two currents match ; higher the chances of the above transistor to go to triode.

Such circuits are always operated in negative feedback loop.